# How to render rectangles in a D3 grouped bar chart using React Faux DOM?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I am achingly close to finishing a group bar chart in React using `react-faux-dom` package. Everything is set except for the actual rectangles. Been spinning my wheels for a few hours so I'm hoping someone can see what I'm missing. The example that I'm working from [is here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152). My goal is to have a time scale x-axis with multi bar groups. The X and Y axes are currently rendering without issue.

Data structure currently looks like so:

```
[
  {key: "oauths", values: [
    { date: Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT-1000 (HST), key: "oauths", value: 3060},
    { date: Tue Jul 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT-1000 (HST), key: "oauths", value: 2060},
    { date: Tue Jul 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT-1000 (HST), key: "oauths", value: 3270},
  ...]},
  {key: "user_stats", values: [
    { date: Tue Jul 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT-1000 (HST), key: "user_stats", value: 2976},
    ...
  ]}
]
```

The React component's render method is below. It error on the final `svg.append()...`

```
render() {
    const data = [ {}, {} ]; // see above

    // Constants
    const margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
          width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          n = this.props.dataQueryPeriod.length, // number of samples
          m = 2; // number of series

    // Parse the date / time
    const parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    // Set ranges
    const yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    const x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(n))
      .rangeBands([0, width], .2);

    const x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(m))
      .rangeBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

    const xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

    // Test colors
    var z = d3.scale.category10();

    // Define axes
    const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(d3.time.days);

    const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

    // Convert structured data to nested data
    const nest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.key; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending);

    // Create node
    let node = ReactFauxDOM.createElement('svg');

    let svg = d3.select(node)
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom+40)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.value = +d.value;
    });

    const nestedData = nest.entries(data);
    console.log("nested data", nestedData);
    console.log("pre nest data", data);

    // Define axes domains
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", ".15em")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(-65)";
          });

    svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
        .data(nestedData)
      .enter().append("g")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return `translate(${x1(i)},0)`; })
      .selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d.value; })
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", yScale)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x0(i); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value); });

    return node.toReact();
  }
```

Comment: If you append isn't it already selected? That `svg.append("g").selectAll("g")` seems extraneous to me. What is the exact error you're getting?

Edit: Oh, I see, that's how the original example is. The error would be very useful though.

Comment: Better still, if you can get this running in JSFiddle I can take a closer look :) if we're both convinced it's a bug, please feel free to raise an issue, maybe add this as a test case.

Comment: @Kwhitejr I also happen to consider work a *distraction*. Not sure why, but Mr. Bossman strongly disagrees.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly isn't working? A [minimal runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is starting out like the example you  provided, it's already nested and d3.nest(). Assuming that the data from your example is `nestedData`, then your problem is that you need to bind `values` not `value`. See below:

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(nestedData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return `translate(${x1(i)},0)`; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; }) // This needs to be values
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", yScale)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x0(i); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value); });
```